# Encoding a new categorical label column for data based on value

Tags: python, r, encoding

I have a dataset that is a daily record of the price of a commodity. Based on the price data, I would like to encode a new "action" variable. This variable should label each row of the price data with a -1, 0, or 1. These numbers would correspond to "sell, do nothing, buy". I can do this in R or Python. What would the most effective method be?

Sample input:

```
8/26/2017, 5
8/27/2017, 5
8/28/17, 1
8/29/17, 3
8/30/17, 5
```

Sample output:

```
8/26/2017, -1
8/27/2017, -1
8/28/17, 1
8/29/17, 0
8/30/17, -1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match` to index this in `R`

```
df1$price <- c(-1, 1, 0)[match(df1$price, c(5, 1, 3))]
df1$price
#[1] -1 -1  1  0 -1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("8/26/2017", "8/27/2017", "8/28/17", 
"8/29/17", "8/30/17"), price = c(5, 5, 1, 3, 5)), .Names = c("date", 
"price"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Here is the thing though: I have thousands of rows. I do not want to classify each one myself. The program must automatically do this for me based on parameter: for example, if x increases by 20% then classify as sell

Comment: @zsad512  Here is another thing though.  Using a small example and without mentioning anything in the post and when you get an answer, come up with also these things is not good.  If the index is not based on any pattern i.e. if it is custom, then you need to have a key/value pair for that.  Otherwise, the program doesn't automatically find it

Comment: @zsad512  You can check your own post `This variable should label each row of the price data with a -1, 0, or 1`  How do others know if there are more indexes..